# Construct second–order constant coefficient ODE from the time–1 map.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem from "A Modern Introduction to Dynamical Systems" of R. J. Brown. The statement reads

> For $r<0$ a constant, construct a second–order constant coefficient ODE whose time–1 map is $f(x)=rx$. (*Hint:* Work with the first-order system and then convert back at the end).

My attempt to solve the problem starts by knowing that every second–order constant coefficient ODE is given by
$$ \ddot{x}(t) + a\dot{x}(t) + bx(t) = 0 $$
with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. We know that a possible solution for this equation (even if it isn't the general solution) is
$$ x(t) = ce^{\lambda t} \qquad\text{with}\qquad \lambda = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} $$
and also considering the boundaries
$$ x(0) = x_0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad x(1) = f(x_0) = rx_0 $$

I have that
$$ x(0) = x_0 = c $$
and
$$ x(1) = rx_0 = ce^{\lambda} $$
and that means that
$$ \ln(r) = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} $$
but I don't know how to proceed from here.

---

There is also a solution online, that can be found [here](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Ebrown/courses/s18/Solutions_old/Problem16.pdf), but I don't understand how does he transforms $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ to $g:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and just substitutes $n$ to $t$ to find the equation for $g$.

[image: "First part of the solution found on the link above"]

Answer (score 1):

You have $\lambda=\ln(r)=\ln|r|+i\pi$, since $r<0$. Therefore, the second-order ODE is given by
$$
(D-\lambda)(D-\bar{\lambda})x=0\implies (D^2-(\lambda+\bar{\lambda})D+\lambda\bar{\lambda}D)x=0, \tag{1}
$$
where $D:=\frac{d}{dt}$. The real solutions to $(1)$ are given by
$$
x(t)=e^{t\ln|r|}(A\cos(\pi t)+B\sin(\pi t))=|r|^t(A\cos(\pi t)+B\sin(\pi t)). \tag{2}
$$
They satisfy $x(1)=-|r|x(0)=rx(0)$.